# assigning multiple variables in python at loop at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, printf

i was wondering if i could assign multiple variable in single statement from user input and use them in the next step

#orginal code:

```
Test=int(input())
while(Test):
    a=list(map(int,input().split()))
    print(hcf(a[0],a[1]),gcd(a[0],a[1]))
    Test-=1
```

#i have figured this code getting error while assigning values to variable a

```
[a=list(map(int,input().split())),print(hcf(a[0],a[1]),gcd(a[0],a[1])) for x in range(int(input()))]
```

is it possible to write?

Comment: List comprehensions should only be used when you want to make a list of the results of an expression. Don't use them as a general shortcut for looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension is not always preferred but if you really wanna do this with list comprehension this is how to do it :

```py
[print(hcf(a[0],a[1]),gcd(a[0],a[1])) for ctr in range(int(input())) for a in list(list(map(int,input().split())))]
```

Refer [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-list-comprehensions-in-python/#:%7E:text=List%20Comprehensions%20are%20one%20of,similar%20to%20nested%20for%20loops.) to understand list comprehension of nested for loops better
simply,
The inner most for loop appears at the right..

The above code is same as :

```py
for ctr in range(int(input())):
    for a in list(list(map(int,input().split()))):
        print(hcf(a[0],a[1]),gcd(a[0],a[1]))
```

Comment: `[print(hcf(data[0],data[1]),gcd(data[0],data[1])) for testcase in range(int(input())) for data in [list(map(int,input().split()))]]`